# What is closure? It is supposed to be included in Java 7

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a closure? Does java have closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805474/what-is-a-closure-does-java-have-closures)
>   [Closure in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443510/closure-in-java-7)

***What is closure?*** 
It is supposed to be included in Java 7. 
Can anyone please provide me with some reliable references from where I can learn stuff about closures?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)#Local_classes_.28Java.29

Comment: @JamesAllardice it's like he copied that question word for word. Amazing.

Comment: Closures is supposed to be in Java 8 and its format will be much the same as in C# so that might be a good place to start. http://java.dzone.com/news/java-8-lambda-syntax-closures (This has a link to a page written by the designer of closures in Java 8)