# Explain why anonymous functions in Javascript can access variables in the outer function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Before I begin, I realize that the ECMA script specification will probably answer my question, but I am asking it on SO in hope of a comprehensible answer.

Take the following code:

```
function test1(param) {
    alert(param);
}

function test2() {
    var testvar = 99;
    setTimeout(function(){ test1(testvar); }, 1000);
}

test2();
```

If I run this code, I get a popup box showing 99. 
My question is, in `test2`, shouldn't `testvar` be null after `test2` finishes running? How does the anonymous function in `setTimeout` get the value of `testvar`? Is there some sort of stack copying going on right as setTimeout gets called?

Comment: Go grab a bottle of vodka and read this question. I'd try to give you an answer but my office has a no alcohol policy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of *[closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)*. Functions in JavaScript retain references to -- "close over" -- variables defined in their lexical scope. That is, all variables that can be referenced when the function given to `setTimeout` is created can be referenced long after `test2` has returned.

In this way, a closure is both a function and a set of bindings to the variables that were in scope when the function was created. This is why closures are sometimes called [poor man's objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497801/closures-are-poor-mans-objects-and-vice-versa-what-does-this-mean) (and *vice versa*).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was actually a name for this. You would think that in my 4 years as a computer science undergraduate, they would have as least mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due to [Javascript Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). Essentially, variables available to a function at the time it is defined will always be available to it, no matter where it is called from.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). You're basically right about what happens, the variables from the surrounding scope get saved if they're needed in an anonymous function.