# What is the usage scenario of kotlin overloading the invoke operator?

Tags: kotlin

Why not use top-level functions but overloaded invoke operators?
Is there any advantage to overloading the invoke operator?

```kotlin
class GetFollowableTopicsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val topicsRepository: TopicsRepository,
    private val userDataRepository: UserDataRepository
) {

  operator fun invoke(sortBy: TopicSortField = NONE): Flow<List<FollowableTopic>> 
  ...

}
```

Comment: How would you use top level functions instead of overloading the invoke operator in this case?

Comment: @Sweeper Use the code in `invoke()` as the body of the top-level function.

Comment: But where would that function get `topicsRepository` and `userDataRepository` from? They can be passed as parameters, but then you need to pass them on each call; here you construct (or get from the DI framework) a `GetFollowableTopicsUseCase` once to fix both.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt Sorry, but just to be clear: do you mean the comment answers your question (and should be an answer), or that you already understood this?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, your comment is the answer to my question, the other answers are generic. After these few days, I have thought of this myself. By the way, I should have replied to one of your comments, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`invoke` can use properties and methods of the class it's defined in. If you try to make it a top-level function you would likely need to pass `topicsRepository` and `userDataRepository` as arguments, but you'd have to do so on every call. And if you need to calculate something from them which doesn't depend on the `sortBy` argument, you'd have to repeat the calculation each time (or use some workaround).

When `invoke` is a class method, you can construct (or get from the DI framework) a `GetFollowableTopicsUseCase` once to fix both and do any calculations which don't depend on `sortBy` in the constructor or lazy property initializers.

Answer (score 3):

There's an old [pair of sayings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497801/closures-are-poor-mans-objects-and-vice-versa-what-does-this-mean) that floats around programming communities like these.

> Closures are a poor man's objects, and objects are a poor man's closures.

The fact of the matter is that, in a sufficiently modern language like Kotlin (or like most languages that we use nowadays), objects and closures are pretty similar. You could replace every class in your Kotlin program with a mess of functions and mutable variables they close over. Likewise, you could replace every function in your program with an object that has an `invoke` function. But the former would be a constant wrestling match with the type system, and the latter would be absurdly verbose.

So Kotlin lets us do both. Which should you use? The advantage of functions is that they're short and snappy and to-the-point. And, to a functional programmer at least, functions should generally be free of side-effects. Objects, on the other hand, are loud and verbose. That's a bad thing, in that it takes longer to read and comprehend when skimming the code. But it's also a good thing, because it stops you from hiding complexity.

So if your function is simple, use a function. If it's complicated or stateful, use a named object and document it like any public class. As a few examples, here's how I would handle some different situations.

- A function to add two numbers together is simple, side-effect-free, and referentially transparent. Use a function.
- A function to add a number to a local `val` is still very simple. It's a closure, but the `val` is immutable, so the function's behavior is predictable. Using an object would be overkill, so make it a function.
- A function that keeps track of how many times it's been called and prints out that number each time has side effects and local state. While it *could* be written as a fancy closure around a `var`, it would be better to make this a real object, whose counter variable is a genuine instance variable, so that anyone reading the code can see at a glance what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Silvio's general answer, one specific case is for factory methods.

If you define a factory method like this:

```
class MyClass(…) {
    …
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(…): MyClass = …
    }
}
```

Then calling the factory method looks exactly like calling a constructor: `MyClass(…)`. This makes factory methods, with all their [advantages](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/item-30-consider-factory-functions-instead-of-constructors-e1c747fc475), easier to use and hence more likely to be adopted.

(Obviously, this only makes sense when the parameter type(s) clearly distinguish the factory method from any public constructors, and also clearly indicate its purpose. In other cases, named factory methods are preferable.)