# Add function in functional implementation of dictionary in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I referenced codes in this question: [How to implement a dictionary as a function in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708701/how-to-implement-a-dictionary-as-a-function-in-ocaml), and I wrote my code of functional dictionary in OCaml:

```
type key = string;;
type 'a dict = key -> 'a option;;
let add (d : 'a dict) (k, v) : 'a dict = fun k' -> if k' = k then v else d k';;
let empty () = ... ;;
let find d k = ... ;;
```

In this code, what I want to know is how the add function works. What does the variable `k'` mean? When we use `fun` keyword, for example, `let sub x = fun y -> x - y;;`, the variable that comes next to the `fun` means an argument. Is it right? When I want to use the `sub` function I defined, we can call the function with

```
# sub 1 2;;
- : int = -1
```

and `2` is an argument that is bound to `y`, which is the variable next to the `fun` keyword. However, in the dictionary code above, there is the variable `k'` in the `add` function, next to the `fun` keyword, but it does not represent any additional argument. Arguments that are needed to call the `add` function is a `'a dict` type variable and a `(k, v)` type tuple. No third argument is required. Then, what does the `k'` mean? I have no idea.

Comment: `k'` is the key that you're searching for. If `k'` is equal to `k` then you've found the key and hence you return the corresponding value, i.e. `v`. Otherwise, you search for `k'` in the rest of the dictionary, i.e. `d`, by applying `d` to `k'`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Hmm.... Then, where does the ```k'``` come from? There is no variable named ```k'``` in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OCaml,

```
let sub x y = x - y
```

is a shorthand notation (the syntactic sugar) for

```
let sub = fun x -> fun y -> x - y
```

To get it, let's pick an even simpler example,

```
let succ x = x + 1
```

is the shorter syntactic form for

```
let succ = fun x -> x + 1
```

which says that we bind the name `succ` to a function `fun x -> x + 1`, where the latter is the function literal. A literal in programming languages is the syntactic notation for defining values. For example, for integers we have a finite set of literals `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. For strings, we have a practically infinite set of literals, e.g., `"hello"`, `""`, `"etc"`. A function in OCaml is also a value, the same as an integer or a string, therefore it has a syntax for function literals, which is

```
fun <arg> -> <body>
```

It creates a function, that evaluates to the value of `<body>` in which all free occurrences of `<arg>` are substituted be the actually passed parameter.

As you probably noticed, we could really bind only one parameter in the function literal. Indeed, all functions in OCaml are unary. You may already know that you can define functions like `fun x y -> x - y`, but this is also just syntactic sugar for `fun x -> fun y -> x - y`. So what the latter notation means? Let's ascribe parenthesis to get the idea of how this function is evaluated:

```
 fun x -> (fun y -> x - y)
```

So we can recognize the `fun x -> <body>` part, where `<body>` is a function on itself, i.e., `<body> = fun y -> x - y`. That means that expression `fun x -> fun y -> x - y` is a function, that takes an argument `x` and returns another function, that takes an argument `y` and returns `x-y`. This way of defining functions, i.e., when instead of having functions that accept tuples you have a function that returns a function and so on, is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Now, when we are comfortable with the idea of currying and that all functions in OCaml are really of one argument, we can go back to the original example of the functional dictionaries.

The add function

```
let add (d : 'a dict) (k, v) : 'a dict = fun k' -> if k' = k then v else d k'
```

stripped of the (unnecessary) type annotations

```
let add d (k, v) = fun k' -> if k' = k then v else d k'
```

and then represented in the form that makes currying explicit, is

```
let add = fun d -> fun (k, v) -> fun k' -> if k' = k then v else d k'
```

So it is a function that for given dictionary `d` produces a function that takes a pair `(k,v)` and returns a function that for all `k'` that are equal to `k` will return `d`. And if keys are different, then it applies the key to the first parameter `d`. Let's take a deeper look at the

```
fun k' -> if k' = k then v else d k'
```

literal. As we can see variables `d` and `k` occur free in that function, i.e., they are not bound by the parameter `k`. When a function references a variable from the outer scope (which is not defined on the module level), a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) is created. A closure is an opaque object that contains a pointer to the code<sup>1</sup> (in our case it is `if k' = k then v else d k'` and pointers to each *captured* variable (i.e., to each variable that is taken from the outer scope). In our case, it creates (roughly) a record that has three entries, `d`, `k` and the code. After a few hours of mediation, it is not hard to see, that a function dictionary is just singly-linked list of closures, as `d` is a pointer to the closure, which, in turn, contains a pointer to another closure, until we reach the pointer to `empty`, which returns `None` no matter the key (and is coded incorrectly in your example, as it should expect any key, not for the value of type unit).

With all that said and kept in mind, we can now write the short-hand notation for the `add` function:

```
let add d k k' = if k' = k then v else d k'
```

which has absolutely the same semantics (i.e., meaning, behavior) as any other notations, as it is just the syntactic sugar.

---

<sup>1)</sup>To prevent any confusion, the code itself is never stored in the heap memory. Even when you have an anonymous function that is not bound to any name, e.g., `(fun x y -> x + y) 2 3` the compiler will emit the code and store it in the text section of a binary and give it some funny name. So the code above will be just a normal call to a function with mangled name, e.g., `call Testing_fun001`. And going back to the functional dictionary example, each entry will be an object with three words, the key, the data, the pointer to the next entry. Basically the same underlying representation as an association list.

Answer (score 0):

About your type definitions..

```
type key = string;;
type 'a dict = key -> 'a option;;
```

Why not...

```
type 'a dict = 'a -> 'a option;;
```

Or even better...

```
type ('a, 'b) dict = 'a -> 'b option;;
```